# 300ms delay not working on ion-item

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a big ion-list, with, ion-item(s) with a ng-click, href, etc inside a ion-content.
On the first tap to scroll up, the ion-item will get activated and background color will change. It happens if I have ion-option-button(s) too.

I've made this codepen: codepen.io/anon/pen/JRjbOR

So, how can I add the 300ms touch delay to ion-itens without turn it into a button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [on-tap directive](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onTap/).

Comment: on-tap don't work for ion-item elements. Try my codepen.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a temporary solution for this issue:

Changed ionic.bundle.js on line 3290, after if (eleToActivate) { added:

```
//Delay for item-content
      if (eleToActivate.classList && eleToActivate.classList.contains('item-content')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          queueElements[keyId] = eleToActivate;
          ionic.requestAnimationFrame(activateElements);
          keyId = (keyId > 29 ? 0 : keyId + 1);
        },200);
        return;
      }
```

This way, I have a 200ms delay on tapping ion-item.